# MeteorJS Functionality

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm very new to Meteor and looking to start my new project in it as the system looks great.

Before I commit myself and dive straight in to code, I have a few queries about whether some planned features are possible with MeteorJS.

- Creating a Follow Relationship
- Getting a users recent posts
- Invite Only System
- Scoring system similar to Product Hunt

I realise that there is Telescope which would make this for me, but I want to learn the language from the ground up and not just have a plugin in create everything for me.

Comment: This is a very odd question. Meteor is based on Node. From that, you can do pretty much anything with it... There's a lot of resources around to help you build whatever, be it using Node or using Meteor.

Comment: The things you're after are things that can be built in **any framework ever made**, in **any language ever made**. You need to be far, far more specific  with your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the functionality you are looking for is possible with Meteor. If you really want to learn meteor take a look at this [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Meteor/comments/2gjemf/best_resources_to_learn_meteorjs/'Reddit%20thread') thread. My personal choice is [eventedmind.com](http://eventedmind.com) I found that, for me, the material is easy to understand and very in depth, it gives me a solid understanding of the Meteor system not just fast prototyping/scaffolding. I also purchased the Discover Meteor book and found it to be rich and informative.

I highly recommend taking a close look at meteor, it amazing!